# Sencha Architect ExtJS Build Size

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

I am using Sencha Architect to create ExtJS 5 project which is resulting of size 100 Mb(It is just one form panel). I need to embed this extjs project in an existing J2EE app and thus will cause performance issues and will unnecessarily increase the size of the project. 
Could you please suggest a way to shrink the size of the project generated by sencha architect or any other workaround for the same?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sencha CMD to compress all your files.Basically how it works is, it takes all your js files and minifies them to single allclasses.js file.
This link will help you to get started ( current sencha cmd version is 5)

http://blogs.walkingtree.in/2013/04/09/create-build-sencha-extjs-project-using-sencha-cmd-3/